# Can I Reduce the Size of Root Persistent Disk of Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am running a wordpress site on google compute engine, it started very well until today......

As the site is intended for user to create contents, I was testing how to increase the size of the persistent disk.

Yes, it is possible and easy, however, it seems not possible to reduce or return to the original size of the disk.

It was 10GB and now it is 10TB, which heavily increased my cost and it is totally unnecessary.

Is there any way that I can reduce the size of the root disk?

I tried to create a new disk from snapshot, but it cannot be attached to the current instance with error "feature not supported".

I think it maybe possible to create a new instance with the snapshot but it will cost me to buy a new SSL cert., however, I guess it could be the last or best option.

Anyone can help?

Thank you so much!

Renfred

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, you go to options for the instance, and edit them to make sure the "Delete boot disk when instance is deleted" is not selected. This will allow you to delete your current instance. Doing that you can maintain your original IP address etc.

Try to see if that lets you just put the snapshot on a smaller disk without your instance.

From here you can create an image from the disk.

And try to create a new disk from the disk image.

Be sure to have everything backed up etc. Don't delete anything (other then the instance) until you have a working thing back up. And triple check that you won't lose the disk when you trash the instance.

Then when you're back up and running. Make sure you get rid of the stuff you really don't need. You could still have the 10TB disk if you don't delete it. But, avoid that until you have something working again.

In both cases, you would be maintaining the IP address and the webhost. I don't see how that cert no longer matches that. You would be provisioning a new machine in place. Same IP address, same URL, even in the worst cast where you go rid of instance altogether, and start fresh. But, paying 260 bucks a month is a non-starter.